# jquery remove last created element

Tags: php, ajax, dom, jquery

I need some help with removing some elements from my page with jQuery, currently I have PHP loop that builds links,

```
    <?php
    $findMore = array();
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($backgrounds as $row) :
?>
    <a id="<?=$i;?>" class="findOutMore" href="<?=$row['backgroundAddress']; ?>">Find Out More</a>
<?php
    $i++;
    endforeach;
?>
```

This creates links that have display none, on then each time the rel of link chages some where else in the HTML then a new link is displayed using this code,

```
function setCurrent(i){
    i = parseInt(i)+1;
    $("li", "#" + options.numericId).removeClass("current");
    $("li#" + options.numericId + i).addClass("current");
    var rel = $('ol#controls li.current a').attr('rel');
    if($('a#'+rel).hasClass('findOutMore')) {
        $('a#'+rel).css({
            display:'block',
        })
    }
};
```

So everytime the rel changes I get a new link on the page but i need the previous link to dissapear? Is this possible and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure I understood your question, but if you want only one link with the 'findOutMore' class shown at a time, I would do the following (just at the end of your code):

```
var rel = $('ol#controls li.current a').attr('rel');
if($('a#'+rel).hasClass('findOutMore')) {
    $('a.findOutMore:visible').hide();
    $('a#'+rel).show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call

```
$(".findOutMore").hide();
```

before showing the new link. The idea is that all links of interest have the same class, so that can be easily hidden.